# Loop with http get request returns scrambled data Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, observable

I have a loop, in which there is a http `GET` request.

Loop code:

```
for (let index = 0; index < datas.length; index++) {
   let car = datas[index].smiles;
   console.log('or--> ' + car);
    this.subscr = this.CarService.getCarForm(car).subscribe((val) => {
     console.log(val);
     });
 }
```

The `GET` request is a service:

```
public getCarForm(car: string) {
   return this.http.get(this.url_conn + this.encode(car), {
    responseType: 'text',
  });
 }
```

The result of the loop is:
`"1", "3", "5", "4", "2"`

Instead of:
`"1", "2", "3", "4', "5'`

I am using:

- `rxjs:  7.8.0`
- `angular/cli: 15.1.6`

I have tried using `pipe(first())`, `unsubscribing()`, separate the `GET` request in new function; using a `Promise` instead of `Observable`.
The result is always the same.

Comment: By definition subscription executes when *asynchronous* http call completes, hence why the logs are "out of order". [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) is one option. It takes array of observables emits an array (same order) with the last values the array items emitted

Comment: These are asynchronous requests. Suppose that you order 10 amazon products, you won't receive them in the same order you bought them. So either you wait for the first one to finish before calling the next one, or you call all of them at once and reorder them at the end. Another option is to change the API, that seems to be broken because you should never have to do such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there could be a couple of reasons for this behavior, the reason could be in the backend api if you are indexing the response by some parameter sent from the front end, if not then try these methods.

observables initiate calls even if the last call response arrived or not they initiate another call and return responses as they arrive, so there is no sequence of which will come when.
and even if you use a promise you need to make the loop pause until the response, which is hectic. like you would need to take the service call in a separate function wrap it in a promise that resolves on response from the observable subscription.

Or you can use the rxjs operator switch map.
make an observable and loop the call as next and add a switch map on the observable you make.
or you can use forkjoin.
forkjoin takes an array and will wait for all calls in the array to complete and send response then it will emit values/responses in the same order the calls were made in the array.

check the link below it shows a synced loop calls behavior using observables and switchmap() operator or ForkJoin.

switchmap operator: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/using-switchmap-in-angular/

forkJoin operator: https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61

```
async loopCallsFunction () {
  //callResponses = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < datas.length; index++) {
   let car = datas[index].smiles;
   await this.syncCalls(car).then(res=> console.log(res) );
   //or you can add each response in an array
   //await this.syncCalls(car).then(res=> callResponses.push(res) );
  }
 }
 
 syncCalls (car) {
  return new Promise((reject,resolve)=>{
      this.subscr = this.CarService.getCarForm(car).subscribe((val) => {
          if (val) {
            resolve(val);
          } else {
            reject();
          }
        },(error)=>{
            reject(error); 
          });
    });
 }
```

Comment: 1) your implementation of transforming the observable to promise is incorrect. it does not reject on error.
2) you could use  `firstValueFrom` fn from `rxjs` that does the same.

Comment: come on bro you just have to add the error part in the observable subscription, I was giving solutions to the problem and not doing the code for him to just copy past, supporting teaching and suggesting are different from spoon feeding. an angular developer using observables must know about the error part in subscription.

Comment: this developer obviously does not know the difference and where to put reject as do not many other developers coming to read your answer. Your answer is wrong and causes bugs. Even the OP has come up with much better solution. Therefore the downvote. I value your effort though, your solution aims correctly, but has bugs.

Comment: okay thanks, ill keep that in mind for future. as i'm new to this answering think i recently started it. i'll be specific and give a code that will solve the problem without bugs, but if i missed something it can always be discussed with me by the one who is facing the problem. we all make mistakes. BTW thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do this as suggested with forkJoin.
Code:

```
let observables: Observable<any>[] = [];
for (let index = 0; index < datas.length; index++) {
   let car = datas[index].smiles;
    observables.push(this.CarService.getCarForm(car))
 }

forkJoin(observables).subscribe(console.log)
```

The code works. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this.